# In C++ can you use one empty type as storage for another?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, strict-aliasing

In C++, with reference to the standard, is it safe to use placement `new` to obtain a pointer to a struct with no members, using another struct with no members as storage? Something like the following:

```cpp
struct S1 {};
struct S2 {};

S1 s1;
S2* s2 = new (&s1) S2;
```

The intuitive reason I might expect this to work is that you "can't do anything" with the pointer—there are no members in the struct to access, so there's no way to use this (as far as I can see) to access memory that you shouldn't access. But I'm interested in what the standard says about this, with citations.

Assuming this is fine, is it also fine for any types `X` and `Y` such that `std::is_empty<X>` and `std::is_empty<Y>` are both true, assuming you don't forget to make an explicit destructor call?

---

The reason I'm interested in this question is that I have a class like this, which packages up the logic necessary to delay construction of another object:

```cpp
// A container for an object of type T that can be constructed/destroyed at
// will. This is like std::optional but without the overhead of the presence
// bit.
template <typename T>
class ManuallyConstructed {
 public:
  // Starts uninitialized.
  ManuallyConstructed() = default;
  
  // REQUIRES: not initialized.
  ~ManuallyConstructed() = default;
  
  // Initialize or destroy.
  void Init();
  void Destroy();
  
  // REQUIRES: currently initialized.
  T& operator*();
 
 private:
  // Storage for the object, initialized with placement new by Init.
  alignas(T) char storage_[sizeof(T)];
};
```

When `T` is empty according to `std::is_empty`, I'd like `ManuallyConstructed<T>` also to be empty. This allows it to benefit from `[[no_unique_address]]` transparently whenever `T` would. But it means I need to use an empty type for the storage member, and I still need to be able to provide a `T&` from the implementation of `operator*`.

Comment: When class T is empty and trivial - in specialization ManuallyConstructed for such classes you can just privately derive from  such T - and have `Init()`, `Destroy()` empty and `operator*()` returns `*this` - thus empty base class optimization will apply. But if T is not trivial, its constructor or destructor has side effect - I am afraid even empty class has size of 1.

Comment: I don't want to use the empty base class optimization, because it doesn't work with final types.

Comment: _"Assuming this is fine, is it also fine for any types `X` and `Y` such that `std::is_empty<X>` and `std::is_empty<Y>` are both true?"_ — Relevant example: https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.memobj#basic.life-example-4.

Comment: Thanks, yes! That example is really good, it sort of implies that there's no problem as long as you ensure an explicit destructor call to match the placement `new`. (I'll update my question to mention that.) That makes me think this _is_ legal, but I'd like to get a more definitive answer than the implication of an example.

Comment: Well, then you can do specialization with empty base class optimization for empty, trivial and not final. I guess empty classes being final are quite rare.

Comment: Sure, but that's not what I asked here. I'd like to do this correctly whether the type is final or not, whether that's rare or not. This question is tagged language-lawyer for a reason. :-)

Comment: Where is type punning in your code?

Comment: I may have misused the term; could you enlighten me?

Comment: `S2* s2 = reinterpret_cast<S2*>(&s1);` would be type punning.

Comment: Okay yes thanks, I guess I've misused the term (which isn't precise in the first place). I edited the title to remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is allowed by the standard, as long as the size and alignment matches. [[basic.life]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.life#1) says:

> The lifetime of an object of type `T` begins when:
>
> - storage with the proper alignment and size for type `T` is obtained, and
> - its initialization (if any) is complete (including vacuous initialization) ([[dcl.init]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init)),
>
> [...]
>
> The lifetime of an object *o* of type `T` ends when:
>
> - [...]
> - the storage which the object occupies is released, or is reused by an object that is not nested within o ([[intro.object]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.object)).

This is explicitly acknowledging that storage can be reused for another object. There is nothing in [[expr.new]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.new) that seems to say the storage can't come from elsewhere. Placement new [works](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/new.delete.placement) by using an allocation function that just returns the input pointer for storage.

[[basic.life]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.life#9) makes it even clearer that we're talking even about types that are not related through inheritance, providing an example (of UB, but not until the end of the block):

> If a program ends the lifetime of an object of type `T` with static, thread, or automatic storage duration and if `T` has a non-trivial destructor, and another object of the original type does not occupy that same storage location when the implicit destructor call takes place, the behavior of the program is undefined. This is true even if the block is exited with an exception.
>
> Example 3:
>
> ```cpp
> class T { };
> struct B {
>    ~B();
> };
>
> void h() {
>    B b;
>    new (&b) T;
> }                               // undefined behavior at block exit
> ```

Further, the [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51228315/1505451) rule in [[basic.lval]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.lval#11) is not violated, because to violate it you have to make an access, and an access is [defined](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/defns.access) to involving reading or modifying the value of an object. The definition explicitly notes that that only scalars can be accessed, and there are no scalars here. This is the intuition behind "can't do anything with it" in the original question.

That said, I believe the strict aliasing rule doesn't apply even with non-empty types, since the original object's lifetime has already ended; there is no sense in which we would be accessing it. In fact, I think I've convinced myself that this pattern is legal in general even for non-empty types, again as long as the size and alignment are correct.

Comment: The strict aliasing rule can't possibly be relevant in the first place, because OP isn't trying to use a pointer or lvalue to an object of a different type at all. The pointer returned by `new` points to the new object. That there is another object out-of-lifetime in that storage previously is just completely irrelevant. There is no type punning happening. However [basic.lval] is not the only thing that _could_ be violated if there actually was a type mismatch, e.g. calling a non-static member function with the wrong type would also be UB.

Comment: Also, most forms of using `s1` after the `new` will cause UB as the object it points to is out-of-lifetime. If OP attempts to do "type-punning" in that way (although again `s1` actually points to a `S1` object, not the `S2` one with which it shares storage). And yes, none of all of this depends on the class being empty. It does however depend on `S1`  having a trivial destructor, because otherwise the implicit destructor call at the end of `S1`'s scope or at program end will cause undefined behavior.